# Spring BeanFactory and type search

Tags: java, spring

When using Spring and combining both ProxyFactoryBean and @Inject Provider<>, a massive amount of objects ends up being created during startup.

I've identified the cause as the DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType method. The "@Inject Provider<>" is satisfied by iterating over all bean definitions and searching for one that can satisfy the provider generic parameter. When a FactoryBean is encountered, it is fully initialized first and only then it is queried getObjectType(). However, ProxyFactoryBean are often setup in the applicationContext.xml with a dependency on the bean they proxy. Fully initializing the ProxyFactoryBean cause an instantiation of the inner bean.

All of that is well, unless the inner bean cannot be instantiated at that time - e.g. because it relies on some other beans that cannot be initialized until the original bean (the one with the Provider) is. There is not cyclic dependency, only over-eager initialization.

Example:

```
class Bean1 { @Inject Provider<X> provider;}
class Bean2 { @Inject Bean1 bean1;}

applicationContext.xml:
<bean id="bean1" class="com.rb.springissues.sample.Bean1"/>
<bean id="bean2" class="com.rb.springissues.sample.Bean2"/>
<bean id="bean2Factory" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="target" ref="bean2"/>
    <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

In the above example the flow is (fully managed by Spring):

- Instantiate `bean1`. Try to initialize `bean1` and discover it has a `Provider<X>`.

  - Go through all `BeanDefinition` in the context. For each:

    - if it's a "normal" bean, evaluate the class to see if it fits.
    - if it's a `FactoryBean`, try to instantiate and initialize the `FactoryBean` to see what "`getObjectType()`" would return.

      - In order to initialize `bean2Factory`, it needs to be fed with an instance of `bean2`. So Spring tries to instantiate and  initialize `bean2`.

        - However - `bean2` cannot be initialized since it relies on `bean1` - causing Spring to throw a cyclic dependency error.
    - If the `FactoryObject` was created correctly, Spring now asks for the type and cache the response ("good path").
    - If we got an exception (the cyclic dependency error) it's caught and ignored, but the result isn't cached - so if we get another bean it'll do the same thing again (and again and again...)

See https://github.com/bironran/spring_issues_proxy_factory for the full description and a sample.

I have observed real-world application with about 500 defined beans instantiate and attempt to initialize over 300,000 objects (the same beans again and again) due to this issue. The startup is delayed by minutes and GC spike.

Moreover, this issue has exponential growth - any new dependency that cannot be resolved can double the time the application takes to load.

Would love to hear suggestions on how to solve (see the github project).

Comment: Can you state your business case, that is the problem you're trying to solve? I don't see it here or in your GitHub page. Perhaps we can step back and question the usage of `ProxyFactoryBean` before trying to solve a problem it brings. Unless, of course, this is purely an academic exercise.

Comment: We use ProxyFactoryBean to apply performance monitoring, throttling, transaction management, customer selection (as multi-customer SaaS product) and apply permissions (in select cases).

Comment: So basically, for cross-cutting concerns? I suppose there exists other ways of doing it, but ok.

Comment: yep. "other ways" - if I don't find a solution I'm going to have to explore those other ways. maybe aspectj load-time weaving.

Answer (score 1):

Solution turned out to be easy - replace `<property name="target" ref="bean2"/>` with:

`<property name="targetName">
  <idref bean="bean2"/>
</property>
<property name="targetClass" value="com.rb.springissues.sample.Bean2"/>`

This causes a delayed binding of bean2 - so the factory can be initialized without a Bean2 instance.

Comment: Thanks for posting an update. Sorry I couldn't help you; don't have the appetite to debug XML config anymore. Seems like going back in time.